# MySQL Query result into desired format

Tags: mysql

Hello everyone i have some question about query on MySQL

I have table name TEST like this

```
Column_1    Column_2    Class
5           9           A
2           6           B
4           3           B
7           3           C
```

And i want to make query output like this

```
[[5,9], [2,6], [4,3] ,[7,3]] , ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
```

How/What MySQL query that can make output like that? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: output like this cannot be achieved with relational databases

Comment: you need to write custom function in which you have to create such string and then return that variable

Comment: @IlyaBursov This output can be achieved.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I suppose OP mean actual sets, not string representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why do you want some like that, but you can do it using a mysql query. The response is a string in that format.

**The query:**

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    '[',
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('[', Column_1, ', ', Column_2, ']')),
        ', ',
        CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('''',Class), ''''), ']'),
    ']'
) AS result
FROM TEST
;
```

**Response:** [[5, 9],[2, 6],[4, 3],[7, 3], ['A','B','B','C']]

Comment: when i change that to array, the result is Array ( [0] => [5, 9],[2, 6],[4, 3],[7, 3] ).
How i can change that into Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 9 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 3 ) ).
Thanks

Comment: I think this is another question. Can you please tell us what programming language are you using? and share some code

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this output by using a combination of `GROUP_CONCAT` and `CONCAT`, applied over the entire table:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('[[',
           GROUP_CONCAT(Column_1, ',', Column_2 SEPARATOR '], ['),
           ']] , [''',
           GROUP_CONCAT(Class SEPARATOR ''', ''' ),
           ''']') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

I have the feeling that perhaps you are planning on working with JSON data.  If so, have a look at MySQL's [support for JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html).  Or, you might want to consider handling this output problem in your presentation layer/language.

Comment: when i change that to array, the result is Array ( [0] => [5, 9],[2, 6],[4, 3],[7, 3] ).
How i can change that into Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 9 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 3 ) ).
Thanks